# Issue with Hugepage reservation in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have reserved hugepages for my process using below commands:

```
#echo 64 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
#mkdir -p /mnt/huge  && mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge .
```

And I have placed it in `rc.local` file.

After machine reboot, huge pages reserved successfully and `/mnt/huge` created.

But before my process startups, I could see 21 hugepages are not available for reservation.
Below command output:

```
# cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge 
HugePages_Total: 64 
HugePages_Free: 43 
HugePages_Rsvd: 43 
HugePages_Surp: 0 
Hugepagesize: 2048 kB
```

And no results for the below commands:

```
# lsof |grep /mnt/huge 
[root@CLA-0(11) /root]
```

Then I tried to free hugepages ...

```
# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
```

No error message displayed. But below command output tells no change ..

```
# cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages 
 0
```

But I could see if we `echo > 64` it updates nr_hugepages. Also tested with other numbers, it only updates if value is greater then current value in nr_hugepages.

I am looking  for below clarification in this site:

1. 43 hugepages are free , who requested 21 hugepages allocation out of 64.
2. Why `echo 0 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepage` is not updating nr_hugepages

Linux Kernel

```
# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.34.13-WR4.3.x86_64_fbsa_standard-00038-gc4b8cb8 (gcc version 4.4.1 (Wind River Linux Sourcery G++ 4.4a-431) ) #1 SMP Wed Jan 8 20:40:41 EET 2014
```

Comment: Please fix the format... Oh, god! my eyes!

Comment: i am able to read ... please let me know which line needs fix ??

Comment: Marc B already did the fixing...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a perfect answer to this problem *but* you can obtain usable space using the following

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# 
echo "Re-establishing and defragmenting hugepages "
sysctl -p
hugeadm --pool-pages-min=DEFAULT:+[page-count] –add-temp-swap=400
echo “ “
echo “Updated hugepages “
cat /proc/meminfo |grep HugePage
```

This will consolidate the reserved pages into one place using a swap file of 400 pages (in this case) and attempt to ensure `/` append the required number available pages specified in `[page-count]`. The script assumes you have defined the desired number of initial pages in `/etc/sysctl.conf`
More information in the manual entry for `hugeadm`